# How to block all traffic except established/related in windows

Tags: iptables, windows-firewall

How would you create this configuration in the windows Netfirewall?

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP 
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```